# Вопрос к глаголу с приставкой "по"

Tags: глаголы, аспектология

Если у нас глагол несовершенного вида:

*Гулял*

*Бросал*

*Курил*

*Ел*

*Спал*

То вопрос задаётся **"Что делал?"**

---

Если совершенного вида:

*Пришёл*

*Убил*

*Кинул*

*Сделал*

*Зарисовал*

То вопрос таков - **"Что сделал?"**

---

А если глагол с приставкой **"по"**:

**По***бегал*

**По***говорил*

**По***вытирал*

**По***грустил*

**По***хлопал*

То к таким глаголам вопрос будет **"Что сделал?"** или **"Что поделал?"**.
Если второе, то он тогда считается в совершенного или несовершенного вида?

Answer (score 1):

Определять вид глагола в большом числе случаев можно всего лишь с помощью двух вопросов:

1. Что **сд**елать?
2. Что **д**елать?

Если глагол отвечает на вопрос 1 (что сделать?), он совершенного вида.

Если глагол отвечает на вопрос 2 (что делать?), он несовершенного вида.

Если в разных контекстах глагол может отвечать и на вопрос 1, и на вопрос 2, то этот глагол двувидовой.

Примеры:

***что сделать?*** побегать, прийти, махнуть.

***что делать?*** поглядывать, ухаживать, махать.

***оба вопроса возможны*** арендовать, атаковать, короновать.

Ср.: Я арендовал квартиру, заезжай в гости! vs Я арендовал квартиру, когда был студентом, и жил в ней.

Армия атаковала замок, и он вскоре пал. vs Армия долго атаковала замок, но всё было впустую.

Артура короновали, и он теперь король. vs Артура короновали почти пять часов, это было слишком растянуто...

Comment: Про **двувидовые глаголы** вообще впервые услышал, спасибо!

А в чём тогда разница между **арендовал** и **атаковала** в понимании несовершенного вида от **арендовывал** и **атаковывал**?

Comment: Про разные значения несовершенного вида Раздел 3 Семантика. http://rusgram.ru/Несовершенный_вид